# Using pandas to join on compound keys with mixture of soft and hard keys

Tags: python, pandas, join

I am looking for a way to do partial soft join in pandas which means I have compound join key

```
["soft_key", "hard_key_1", "hard_key_2"]
```

where soft key should be joined on some range, not precise matching.
In `pandas.merge_asof` it is referred as `tolerance`. E.g if key is 10 and tolerance is 2 the following join would happen:

Table1

```
soft_key | hard_key_1 | hard_key_2 | val_1
10       | 2          | 5          | "Jo"
20       | 1          | 1          | "Lu"
```

Table2

```
soft_key | hard_key_1 | hard_key_2 | val_2 
12       | 2          | 5          | "Mary"
10       | 3          | 5          | "Helen"
25       | 1          | 1          | "Nancy"
```

Join

```
val1 | val2
"Jo" | "Mary"
```

*I did not include keys to join for shortness.

Seems like `pandas.merge_asof` would join on a soft-key, but how do I join on a combination of soft and hard keys?

Is it possible to combine somehow

```
table1.merge(table2, how="left", on=[hard_key_1, hard_key2])
```

and

```
pd.merge_asof(table1, table2, on='soft_key', tolerance=2)
```

to achieve the task?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way from `merge_asof`

```
pd.merge_asof(df2.sort_values('soft_key'),df1.sort_values('soft_key'),by=['hard_key_1','hard_key_2'],on='soft_key',tolerance=2).dropna()
   soft_key  hard_key_1  hard_key_2   val_2 val_1
1        12           2           5  "Mary"  "Jo"
```

Comment: thank you, can you elaborate on what is going on in this piece of code?
I guess sorting is required to speed up the join?

Comment: @YohanRoth sorting is must for merge_asof, also you can check the link  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html

Comment: I tested it and it seems that tolerance is considered only in the negative direction, like it is at most the left key, but can be smaller than left key by tolerance amount. is it possible to make tolerance to be +/- instead of just -

Comment: @YohanRoth   adding  the  `direction =‘nearest’` since the default is backward